# How do we get this array output?

Tags: multidimensional-array, array-push

We need this output:

```
$filters = [
    ['property' => 'status.id', 'expression' => '!=', 'value' => 5],
    ['property' => 'status.id', 'expression' => '!=', 'value' => 1],
    ['property' => 'status.id', 'expression' => '!=', 'value' => 7],
];
```

and this way doesn't work:

```
foreach ($orderStatusItems as $orderStatusItem) {
    $filters[] .= "['property' => 'status.id', 'expression' => '!=', 'value' => $orderStatusItem],";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
$orderFilters = [];

foreach ($orderStatusItems as $orderStatusItem) {
    array_push($orderFilters, ['property' => 'status.id', 'expression' => '!=', 'value' => $orderStatusItem]);
}
```